# Proper format for greater/ lesser than DynamoDB conditional updating

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a temp column and a minimum temp column. the temp column is just over written continuously, but when temp is less that minTemp, minTemp is updated to reflect the new low. I know the code below is wrong, 
so my columns are

```
id and date <- these are my keys
temp <- this is the current temperature
minTemp <- this is the lowest temperature for the day
```

And here is the non-working code, but to get an idea of what I am trying to do

```
var tparams = {
    Key: { id: id, date: dayofyear(date)},
    TableName: "myTable",
    UpdateExpression: "Set minTemp = temp",
    ConditionExpression: "temp < minTemp",

    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
    'temp' : 'minTemp
      }
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW" 
  };
console.log(tparams);
```

Why does it just seem the aws docs are of very little help?

Comment: Expression attribute values must begin with a colon. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeValues.html.

Comment: Yes, i actually got it working after i posted this

Comment: Good to hear but please help others to avoid spending time on this by writing up an answer and marking it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me. There could very well be better ways of doing it though

```
attrNamesMinT["#minTemp"] = "minTemp";
attValuesMinT[":mint"] = temperature;

var mintparams = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    Key: { id: id, date: dayofyear(date)},
    UpdateExpression: "Set #minTemp = :mint",
    ConditionExpression: ":mint < #minTemp  or attribute_not_exists(#minTemp)",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: attrNamesMinT,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: attValuesMinT,
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
};


console.log(mintparams);
dynamo.updateItem(mintparams, function(err,res){
    console.log(err);
});
```